# Reverse Geocoding Implementation

Tags: java, android, reverse-geocoding

i am looking to implement reverse geocoding in android  but i am having some problems could someone give me some directions? 
here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
        textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLat);


        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener listener = new myLocationListner();
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);




    }

    public class myLocationListner implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null){

                double gettextLong = location.getLongitude();
                double gettextLat = location.getLatitude();

                textLat.setText(Double.toString(gettextLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(gettextLong));


            }
```

Comment: google api provides reverse geocoding http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Geocoder object and use the .getFromLocation method:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(gettextLat, getTextLong, 1);
```

I.e.:

```
public class myLocationListner implements LocationListener{

    Geocoder mGeocoder;

    // default constructor
    myLocationListener() {
        // instantiate geocoder object:
        mGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null){

            double gettextLong = location.getLongitude();
            double gettextLat = location.getLatitude();

            textLat.setText(Double.toString(gettextLat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(gettextLong));

            List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(gettextLat, getTextLong, 1);

        }
   }
```

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: on the list<add> line i`m getting an error mGeocoder cannot be resolved i tried to declare the geocoder obj inside of onlocChanged but got the same error\

Comment: Sorry - that should have been `mGeocoder` in the `onLocationChanged` function, not `goecoder`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: no problem but i did notice geocoder and replaced it with mGeocoder but  it sais that mGeocoder cannot be resolved on that line. does it not have acces to the geocoder that was created in the onLocationChanged method?

Comment: Ah - sorry - my mistake. Put the instantiation of mGeocoder in a default constructor of your myLocationListener class. See edited answer above.